# My global variable value is not being preserved after deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I serialized a class called GreenhouseControls like this:

```
public class GreenhouseControls extends Controller implements Serializable{

 ......

    public void saveState() {
          try{
              // Serialize data object to a file
              ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("dump.out"));
              out.writeObject(GreenhouseControls.this);
              System.out.println(GreenhouseControls.errorcode); // Prints 1
              out.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
              }
      }

 ......

}
```

When the GreenhouseControls object was serialized, the global static variable 'errorcode' was set to 1.

I then deserialized the GreenhouseControls class like this:

```
public class GreenhouseControls extends Controller implements Serializable{

......

    public class Restore extends Event {

          .....

          @Override
          public void action()  { 
              try {

                  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(eventsFile); 
                  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);  
                  GreenhouseControls gc = (GreenhouseControls) ois.readObject(); 
                  System.out.println("Saved errorcode: " + gc.errorcode); // Prints 0 (the default value)
                  ois.close();        
              }catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } 
          }
      }

......

}
```

When I printed the 'errorcode' to console after deserialization I was expecting a 1 value but instead a 0, the default value for the variable, was printed. Should the static variable's value when it is serialized be preserved after deserialization?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336727/static-class-variables-and-serialization-deserialization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, static variables are not serialized since they exist independently of the instantiated object that you're serializing.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the [answer of Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20692651/97627), the [default Java serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#6250) will serialize variables that are non-transient and non-static. The purpose of serialization is to be able to restore the state of the object from the stream. Since a static variable is not state of this class, but is rather state of the system, it is not serialised.

Note that it is possible, but probably not wise, to serialise statics by implementing [readObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#2971) and [writeObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/output.html#861) methods.

The [Java™ Object Serialization specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/index.html) describes this in more detail than you will ever likely care about ;-)

Comment: to be able to restore the state of the **object**.